# HTTP Upload File with JS

Tags: javascript, php, file, http, upload

I want to upload a file when user presses Ctrl-V in textarea.
I was said i need php POST request handler. I tried to do it by analogy with uploading file from form. But my browser shows
(cannot post image since my reputation below 10. heres the link)(https://c.radikal.ru/c18/2006/09/c2eca4d74442.png)
On the picture the browser shows window saying acknowledge action on page (i translated from russian). In it it shows the result of running php code. The code says "Sorry there was an error uploading your file..."
It seems like i cannot catch the tmp file since echo tmpfile is not seen.

How to write POST handler correctly?

Heres my code:

html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="84%"><input name="topic" type="text" id="topic" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Detail</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="3" id="detail"></textarea></td>
<img id="pastedImage"></img>
</tr>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('detail').onpaste = function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
    this.Files = event.file;
};
let filepath = "upload/images/tmp.png";
//reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
let f = new File([this.Files], filepath);
console.log(f);

//let photo = document.getElementById("image-file").files[0];  // file from input
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("photo", f);                                
call_php();                                
req.open("POST", '/upload/images');
req.send(formData);

}
}

function call_php(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_new_topic.php",
    //data: { file }
  }).done(function( result ) {
    alert(result);
  });
}
```

php:

```
<?php

    $target_dir = "upload/images/test1.png";
    $target_file = $target_dir;// . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    
      // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
      if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";   
      // if everything is ok, try to upload file
      } else {
        echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
          echo "The file ". $target_file. " has been uploaded.";
          $_POST['img'] = $target_file;
        } else {
          echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using both jQuery ajax and vanilla xhr ajax together?

Comment: ive found that req.open("POST", '/upload/images'); is wrong . it shoudl point not to the path of file but to php handler. so it should be: req.open("POST", 'add_new_topic.php');